# YDN-DB full text search plugin not allowing from query

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ydn-db

We have added a separate plugin to implement full-text search with YDN-DB.

Now full text queries are working but all existing queries for get list of data not working. For example:

```
db_mob_audit.from('OrgChildrenNodeInfo').where('IParentID', '=', ParentnodeID).done(
    function (Orgresponse) {
    }
);
```

To make it work we changed the query to:

```
db_mob_audit.values('OrgChildrenNodeInfo', 'IParentID', key_range, 9999).done(
    function (Orgresponse) {
    }
);
```

It is working fine in chrome (IndexedDB).

But in safari browser (-mysql) it gives multiple sets of results again.

Comment: It should work. Could you make a simple unit test?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
db_mob_audit.from('OrgChildrenNodeInfo')
    .where('IParentID', '=', ParentnodeID)
    .list()
    .done(function(Orgresponse) {
      console.log(Orgresponse);
    });
```